# how to get almost same word from database based on one word using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get almost same word based on one word from database.

For example i have word **Online Shopping** in my database.

If I gave whatever word like **online shops**, **Online shop**, **online** mean have to get **Online Shopping** only.

Now I am using below the select code. But its not working fine.

```
**SELECT words FROM atab WHERE words LIKE '%".$words."%'**
```

*Note* : words - column name, atab - table name,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the best way to do this is to return partial matches to any of the words the user enters. Sorting them for relevance is an entirely different matter, but lets start with getting your search to *work* at least:

For the following, I assume that you can get the user search into a variable called `$search` like this:

```
$search='Online Shopping';
```

Now, split the user input into single words:

```
$mSearch=explode(" ", $search);
```

Now we have an array of search items.

With that, we can then make a sensible search query:

```
$sql="SELECT words FROM atab WHERE ";
$or="";
foreach($mSearch as $val)
{
    $sql.=$or." words like '%".$val."%'";
    if(!$or)
    {
        $or=" or ";
    }
}
```

This will now output a SQL like:

```
SELECT words FROM atab WHERE words like '%Online%' or words like '%Shopping%'
```

Which you can run nicely against your database.

Full Code:

```
<?php

    $search='Online Shopping';
    $mSearch=explode(" ", $search);
    $sql="SELECT words FROM atab WHERE ";
    $or="";
    foreach($mSearch as $val)
    {
        $sql.=$or." words like '%".$val."%'";
        if(!$or)
        {
            $or=" or ";
        }
    }
    echo $sql;
?>
```

If you start looking at comparing words that are different but with the same meaning, things start to instantly get orders of magnitude more complex.

Comment: the query you are outputting seems wrong. SELECT words FROM atab WHERE or words like '%Online%' or words like '%Shopping%'. Its having "Where or" in it.

Comment: @fortune I rejected that edit as the `if(!$or)` condition will only pass if there is nothing in `$or` which is what I set it to initially. As soon as there is a value in it, the condition will return false and the if will not be entered.

Comment: @fortune Sorry, I fixed up the code at the top, but not at the bottom. I move the `$sql.=$or." words like '%".$val."%'";` to be above the `if` statement. Sorry form the mixup.

Comment: Now its perfect. Great. +1